# Error al debugear App en Xamarin

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Tengo una App para Android en Xamarin con Visual Studio 2017... pero cuando trato de debugearlo en el Visual Studio 2015 me tira el siguiente error...

**Android application is debugging.**

**The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).**

**Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.**

alguien podría indicarme cual es el problema? Si lo debugeo desde el VS 2017 no tengo ningun problema, pero en el 2015 no hay caso...

Gracias a todos!

Comment: Estas debugeando haciendo el deploy en el emulador o en un telefono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución del problema...

Después de publicar acá, seguí buscando en internet por la solución del inconveniente y es la siguiente...

Ejecuté la App desde el Visual Studio 2017 para que se instale en el dispositivo (en mi caso fue una tablet), luego paré el debug del VS y desinstalé la App... luego de eso fui a la PC donde está instalado el Visual Studio 2015 y ejecuté nuevamente la solución, esta vez sin problema alguno...

El por qué del problema no lo encontré, lo que deduzco es que hay errores de compatibilidad entre las versiones de Xamarin o del SDK entre ambos Visual Studio, ya que la versión 2017 viene integrada con Xamarin y para la versión 2015 hay que instalarlo aparte.

Gracias a todos los que se tomaron el tiempo de leer la publicación.